# Same Content Type Display Name, Different Internal name

Tags: powershell, content-type

I know that you can have internal names and display names for columns but can you also do that for Content Types?

**For example, we have the following with our current powershell script:**

sitecolumninternal1 -> Legal Document

sitecolumninternal2 -> Legal Document

sitecolumninternal3 -> Legal Document

*Three different site columns but same display name.*

**Can you do this with a content type as well?**

internalContentTypeName1 -> MyCTName

internalContentTypeName2 -> MyCTName

internalContentTypeName3 -> MyCTName

We are on premise only at this time.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course you can create contentTypes in lists, with same Name, but different fields. What you will have Troubles with is when you want to do that using SiteCollection ContentTypes.

However, as ContentTypes are supposted to Group equal Contents, i don´t get the Point why you want to confuse everyone with the same Name for different contents

Answer (score 0):

You can not create the two content type with same name.
I have two below content type 
[image]

But when I change the display name of the "Test" content type it shows me the error as below.
[image]